# Converting interest rates

Tags: calculation, interest-rate, apr

I have found a monthly interest rate, 0.72%

Now, I would like to convert this monthly rate to:

1. Equivalent annual nominal rate of interest payable half yearly, and
2. Equivalent annual nominal rate of interest payable weekly

   For 1. I used (i12 + 1)^6 - 1 so (0.72+1)^(6)-1 = 4.41%

   and 2. I used (i12 + 1)^0.230137 = (0.72+1)^(0.230137)-1 = 0.17%

Is this the correct approach?

 Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `m` is the monthly rate 0.72%

```
m = 0.72/100
```

Find the annual effective rate `a = (1 + m)^12 - 1 = 0.0899049` so 9%

The half-yearly rate `h = (1 + a)^(1/2) - 1 = 0.0439851`

so the nominal APR compounded half-yearly is `2 h = 0.0879702` so 8.797%

The weekly rate `w = (1 + a)^(1/52) - 1 = 0.00165696`

so the nominal APR compounded week is `52 w = 0.0861617` so 8.616%

***Check***

The half-yearly, monthly & weekly rates produce the same result when compounded over one year.

```
(1 + h)^2  - 1 = 8.99049%
(1 + m)^12 - 1 = 8.99049%
(1 + w)^52 - 1 = 8.99049%
```

For more info see the [Effective Interest Rate Calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).

Comment: If you assume the monthly rate is based on 30.4 days average, then the weekly rate might be better calculated by: `w = (1 + a)^(7/365) - 1`. This would give a slightly lower rate (8.59%).

Comment: @jiggunjer Indeed, or even w = (1 + a)^(7/[365.2422](https://pumas.nasa.gov/examples/index.php?id=46)) - 1 :-)

Comment: I already accounted for leap years by rounding to 30.4 :-)